# How to access the value of the href key of the dictionary at the second index of an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

The json data is given as follows:

```
 "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "item1",
    "href" : "data1"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item2",
    "href" : "data2"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item3",
    "href" : "data3"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item4",
    "href" : "data4"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item5",
    "href" : "data5"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item6",
    "href" : "data6"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item7",
    "href" : "data7"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item8",
    "href" : "data8"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item9",
    "href" : "data9"
  } ]
}
```

How can I access the href key for value data2 at the second index of the array of links in Swift?

Comment: What is the data type for the variable? This doesn't look like a swift array touple or even json data type. If you can provide more context around the question we would be able to help.

Comment: I have declared an array of dictionaries and like to get the value: data2 for the key href which is at the second index position inside the array links. have declared : var links: [[String: String]]

Comment: Please update your question (don't post comments) with some relevant code. Show what you tried. Clearly explain what issues you are having with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should structure first your data and make it Codable. Then you can get your element property from the array returned from the API. Note that there is a missing bracket at the beginning of your string:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let links: [Links]
}
struct Links: Codable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let rel: String
    let href: String
    var description: String {
        return "Rel: \(rel) - Href: \(href)"
    }
}
```

---

```
let jsonData = Data("""
{"links" : [ {
    "rel" : "item1",
    "href" : "data1"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item2",
    "href" : "data2"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item3",
    "href" : "data3"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item4",
    "href" : "data4"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item5",
    "href" : "data5"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item6",
    "href" : "data6"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item7",
    "href" : "data7"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item8",
    "href" : "data8"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item9",
    "href" : "data9"
  } ]
}
""".utf8)
```

---

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)
    print(root)  // Root(links: [Rel: item1 - Href: data1, Rel: item2 - Href: data2, Rel: item3 - Href: data3, Rel: item4 - Href: data4, Rel: item5 - Href: data5, Rel: item6 - Href: data6, Rel: item7 - Href: data7, Rel: item8 - Href: data8, Rel: item9 - Href: data9])
    let secondLinkHref = root.links[1].href  // "data2"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I do not need you to parse the JSON data for me.
I am facing a syntactical issue as to how to access the second element in the second index via my array of links.
let links: [[String: String]]
data = links[2]-> which is the second index element
after that what should I append to the same and access the key href to store its value in a variable?

Comment: You might not need but you should. You can also create a initialiser for the Root structure that takes an array of dictionaries as the parameter

Comment: Btw `links[1]["href"]` if you really want to insist working with a dictionary instead of structuring your data

Comment: I am not declaring this data. This is the son response that I get after hitting the URL. I just wanna access it, if you may.

Comment: Just use the `data` received from the server instead of my `jsonData` used in my example just for demonstration purposes